# How can i retrieve all the objects from an array based on a query condition?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

consider a table 'users' with following data

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5feb55107c844e84252c05db"), 
  "firstName" : "raj", 
  "lastName" : "kumar", 
  "calories_per_day" : 1800, 
  "phone" : 9955544525, 
  "email" : "rjkrsngh@yahoo.com", 
  "username" : "rjkrsngh", 
  "meals" : [ 
      { 
        "datetime" : ISODate("2020-12-20T16:00:00Z"), 
        "food_name" : "pizza", 
        "calorie" : 400, 
        "description" : "pizza with extra veggies" 
      }, 
      { "datetime" : ISODate("2020-12-21T16:00:00Z"), 
        "food_name" : "wild salmon burgers", 
        "calorie" : 250, 
        "description" : "salmon burger" 
      }, 
      { "datetime" : ISODate("2020-12-21T16:00:00Z"), 
        "food_name" : "pasta", 
        "calorie" : 250, 
        "description" : "green sauce pasta" 
      }, 
      { "datetime" : ISODate("2020-12-21T12:00:00Z"), 
        "food_name" : "palak paneer", 
        "calorie" : 385, 
        "description" : "green palak paneer" 
      } ] 
}
```

From this entry, i want to retrieve all the food consumed by user: 'rjkrsngh' on 21-12-2020 which should be:

```
  { "datetime" : ISODate("2020-12-21T16:00:00Z"), 
    "food_name" : "wild salmon burgers", 
    "calorie" : 250, 
    "description" : "salmon burger" 
  }, 
  { "datetime" : ISODate("2020-12-21T16:00:00Z"), 
    "food_name" : "pasta", 
    "calorie" : 250, 
    "description" : "green sauce pasta" 
  }, 
  { "datetime" : ISODate("2020-12-21T12:00:00Z"), 
    "food_name" : "palak paneer", 
    "calorie" : 385, 
    "description" : "green palak paneer" 
  }
```

using the query:

```
   db.users.find({username:"rjkrsngh"}, {meals: {$elemMatch: {datetime:{$gte:new Date("2020-12-21T00:00:00Z")}}}}).pretty()
```

i get only the first object that matches the query, which is correct as per documentation of $elemMatch. However, i am not able to figure out a way to get all the objects that matches my query.

I tried aggregation query mentioned below too, but didn't work.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { $match: { username: 'rjkrsngh' }},
  { $project: {
      meals: { $filter: {
          input: '$meals',
          as: 'meals',
          cond: { $gte: ['$$meals.datetime', 'new Date("2020-12-21T00:00:00Z")']}
      }},
      _id: 0
  }}
]);
```

Can anyone help me out here!

Comment: your aggregation query is correct you just need to remove single quotes from the date `'new Date("20-12-21T00:00:00Z")'` and correct the year it should be after correction `new Date("2020-12-21T00:00:00Z")`      and $elemMatch return only single matching document from array.

Comment: that was actually a typo, thanks for mentioning it @turivishal